# Making Zuul use separate context path than the spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am using Zuul to forward requests for images from my spring boot app to an image optimization web server (thumbor). The spring server running on `localhost:8080` uses context-path of `/api`. And Zuul forwards requests from `/images/**` to thumbor server running on `localhost:3000`.

So to fetch the images I have to do `localhost:8080/api/images/**` but instead I would want `localhost:8080/images/**`.

I tried the servlet-path configuration provided by zuul but it starts after the servlet context-path of spring boot like `localhost:8080/api/zuul/images/**`.

This is my configuration.

**application.yml**

```
...
server:
    base-url: http://localhost:8080/api/
    port: 8080
    servlet:
        context-path: /api
...
zuul:
    routes:
        thumbor:
            path: /images/**
            url: http://localhost:3000
    servlet-path: /zuul
...
```